# LG WM2101HW front load washer doesn't spin, only moves a little, no error codes

Tags: repair, washing-machine

My washer is twelve years old. Today its behavior changed. When it tries to spin, the drum moves a little, maybe 10 degrees of rotation, but does not spin. An unusual noise is heard during these attempted spins. The unit throws no error codes. As far as it knows, it can complete cycles with no problem. I can turn the drum manually with no problem.

This is a front-load direct-drive washer. I suspect the stator has failed and can't produce a strong enough magnetic field to make the drum turn. The extra current flow from a shorted coil would explain the noise. Does anyone have diagnostic suggestions?

Comment: there are many causes for this. The belt is slipping, bad capacitor, bad connection, bad control board

Comment: So what have you tested to suspect the stator? Or is this just a WAG?

Comment: It's direct drive, there is no belt. I suspected the stator based on my understanding of motors. Clearly the stator is receiving some voltage or no force would be applied to the drum at all to cause it to turn even a little. So the stator having, say, a shorted winding could account for this. I've since accessed the stator and it has no visible damage, and all the terminal pairs read 7.9 ohms, so I think the stator is good. Motor start cap is my next guess.

Comment: Oh, look, there is no start capacitor. Guess this thing uses an inverter in the control module. And if the control module is shot, my odds of finding a replacement at this age are... slim.